# filter by inner value in object

Tags: jquery

I have the following filter in Jquery, which filters data in a object when the user enters a value in an input field, which works fine, however I want to add another filter which checks if the user input matches any Sellers names within the object eg. for country I have `(val.country.search(regex) != -1)` but how would I add one for sellers name as it doesn't have a key name.

**Object:**

```
{
    "28": {
        "name": "Alex",
        "country": "Spain",
        "antiquity": "new client",
        "amount": "2690.58 USD",
        "sellers": {
            "Bob": "2690.58 USD",
            "Harold": "2690.58 USD"
        }
    },
        "29": {
        "name": "Bill",
        "country": "UK",
        "antiquity": "new client",
        "amount": "2690.58 USD",
        "sellers": {
            "Support": "2690.58 USD",
            "admin": "2690.58 USD"
        }
    },
        "30": {
        "name": "Jeff",
        "country": "USA",
        "antiquity": "new client",
        "amount": "2690.58 USD",
        "sellers": {
            "tom": "2690.58 USD",
            "harry": "2690.58 USD"
        }
    }
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
   var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    var output;
    var count = 1;

 $.each(response, function(key, val){
          if ((val.name.search(regex) != -1) || (val.country.search(regex) != -1) || (val.antiquity.search(regex) != -1)){
           ....
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you know that the key is `sellers` - so based off that, you can get the keys (names) of `sellers` and run your regex check:

```
$.each(response, function(key, val){
      if ((val.name.search(regex) != -1) || (val.country.search(regex) != -1) || (val.antiquity.search(regex) != -1)){
       ....
      } else if (Object.keys(val.sellers).some(function(seller) { return seller.search(regex) != -1 })) {
          //sellers matches
      }
    });
```

`Array.some` will test each array value and return true if any of them match. So `Object.keys(val.sellers)` will get you the sellers names in an Array, and then test them against your regex. I put it in the `else if` for readability - it can go in the original `if` with another `||` condition.